# Can't debug Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute - VS2010

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, visual-studio-debugging

I'm facing a `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` error in a WPF application under Framework 4.0 in VS2010.

This collection error only happens when I'm launching the compiled debug version of the program. Problem is I'm unable to trace the error as no intellisence informations are given, and I'm not able to find which line of code this error is about.

What would you do to reach the erroned piece of code? Is there an option to toggle to enable intellisence in debug .exe? I have a message telling me to compile in x86, but this is already compiled in x86 mode.

---

#### Source

Not sure which part of the code I should paste, but it gives an idea about the 'pattern' of the application.

This is my ListView, binded to a List of < AudioFile >

```
<ListView AllowDrop="True" Drop="dropMP3" DragEnter="dropMP3Begin"
GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" UseLayoutRounding="False" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="myTracks" Margin="0" AlternationCount="2" 
Foreground="#FFEFEFEF" FontSize="13.333" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
SizeChanged="myTracks_SizeChanged" Background="Black" 
MouseDoubleClick="myTracksDoubleClick">
```

These are my columns:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}">
    <TextBlock Text="Artist"></TextBlock>
</GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Album" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}"/>
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Length}">
    <Image Source="Icons\clock.png" Height="15"/>              
</GridViewColumn>
```

When application starts

```
myTracks.DataContext = songs;
```

This is my object

```
public class AudioFile
{
    public String Artist { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Album { get; set; }
    public String fileLocation { get; set; }
    public String Length { get; set; }
    public String Track { get; set; }
}
```

When a song is found:

```
void lm_SongFound(AudioFile file)
{
        songs.Add(file);
}
```

Comment: Who creates the song field and which type it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That usually happens when you modify the collection during a `foreach` iteration.

For example:

```
foreach(var item in items){
    items.Remove(item);
}
```

As you can see, the collection is being modified while it is being iterated.

The fact that you don't see the exception may not mean it doesn't exist. Maybe it's being trapped. This used to happen with WPF bindings.

Comment: I have an idea about which binding the error targets, but it is currently only a Add() pattern without foreach. I'm harvesting MP3 in a folder then add MP3 to a playlist (ListView) one by one with a EventHandler. It seems the listView is "internally" using a foreach that is perturbed by the fact there are new mp3 in the playlist.

Comment: Are you using an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Didn't use this keyword in my code, so I guess that no. Is it a better practice?

Comment: It will be useful if you provide a code sample that reproduces the error.

Comment: This is my original question. If I had this part of the code, I would just encapsulate it in a try/catch block. Clearly, problem is: 1. I have an error that I can't find. 2. There is no explicit 'foreach' in my code.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. What I suggested is posing the xaml and the model that is being bound.